# MS Access 2000 to MS Access 2007 migration

Tags: ms-access, oracle11g, ms-access-2007, vba, oracle9i

I have application in MS Access 2000.
It is connected to Oracle 9.2.06 database.

I have to migrate the application to MS Access 2007 and Oracle 11G.

I've created a blank .accdb file and imported all the objects from MS Access 2000 (.mdb) file, except the linked tables

While Linking MS Access 2007 with Oracle 11G database tables, i'm getting an error saying

"ODBC--call failed"

I've checked for Machine DSN, System DSN and its configured well alongwith ODBC Drivers.

Also, when i launch the application i'm getting an error as below:
"Error while connecting to '%Oracle database SID%'"

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you re-created all your ODBC links on your computer (in Administrator panel)?  The ODBC is going to be different from Oracle 9.2 to 11.

Answer (score 0):

you may need to import and reference libraries being used - check the Visual Basic Editor and confirm that all applicable libraries have been brought in.

The previously linked tables may have the credentials saved, or may not - you will have to check the properties of the linked table.